# django order_by value not stored in database

Tags: python, django, django-models, performance

I have a model, `Rating`, which looks something like this:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.upvotes - self.downvotes
```

I have a group of ratings which I need to order by their `total` property. As you can see, it is *not* a value stored in the database. `rating_set.order_by("total")` does not work.

I could use Python's `sorted` function on the list of ratings, with `key=lambda r: r.total`. But this seems to me that it would be rather inefficient and there probably exists a better way from within Django.

Does Django support ordering by derived values? Would I improve performance by making total a value stored in the database?

Comment: I think by using `.extra()` while rendering the queryset will solve your problem. Since the field is returned from the database, they can be sorted (obviously). I doubt if it can be done otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the database has no idea about the `total` property.  It only exists in python. You can replicate the same behavior by using [`extra`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) to have it calculated and sorted by the database.  Like so:

```
Rating.objects.extra(select={'total': "upvotes - downvotes"}).order_by('-total')
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually have another model, `Comment` that has a ForeignKey to a `Rating`. I'm trying to figure out how to order the comments by their total rating, eg `Comments.objects.order_by("rating__total")`. I'm thinking something like this, but I cannot figure out the SQL: `Comments.objects.extra(select={'rating_total': "rating.upvotes - rating.downvotes"}).order_by('-rating_total')`

Comment: Nevermind, I fiqured out the SQL. `SELECT projects_rating.upvotes - projects_rating.downvotes FROM projects_rating WHERE projects_rating.id=rating_id`